# Hi i want to get MAX value in leftJoin or LIMIT 1 in Laravel, how can i do it?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$almacenes = Almacenes::with(['producto'])->
                 leftJoin('albaranes_lineas',function ($k) use ($request){
                     $k->on('almacen.id_producto','=','albaranes_lineas.id_producto');


                 })->where(function ($q) use ($request) {

                $q->where('almacen.id_usuario', $request->usuario);
                $q->where('almacen.id_local', $request->local);
                $q->where('almacen.tipo', $request->tipo);
                $q->whereRaw('HOUR(almacen.created_at) = ?', $request->hora);
                $q->whereDate('almacen.created_at', '=', $request->fecha);
                //$q->where('inventario', 1);


            })->get();
```

how can i limit the value to "1"? I want to get the last field of each row in the table "albaranes_lineas".

Comment: add `$k->max('yourcolumn')->limit(1)` or similar. It might be simpler to define a regular SQL query beforehand

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxValue = Almacenes::with(['producto'])->
                 leftJoin('albaranes_lineas',function ($k) use ($request){
                     $k->on('almacen.id_producto','=','albaranes_lineas.id_producto');
                     $k->where('albaranes_lineas.id',821);
                 })->max('table_name.column_name');
```

When you use `max('column_name')`, it returns a single count value. In this case `$maxValue` will hold the count of your column. This is an aggregate function available in laravel.

You can not call `max()->limit()` as it will be like calling `->limit()` in an integer value and will throw error  :

> Call to a member function limit() on integer

However, if you want to get max for a particular condition, then you you will need group by clause.

Comment: Can u read all? sorry this i know it but i want to limit the leftJoin not, the all

Comment: Can you post raw query please in question or which column you need to aggregate for max?

Comment: I have the model "Almacenes" which i use data of this and i want to join with table "Albaranes_lineas" and they twice doesn't have relationship, and i relation this both tables with the column "id_producto" and i want of "albaranes_lineas" the last data of the column "precio".

Comment: append to the data of the rest of model "Almacenes"